# Triggering and binding to custom events?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

I'm trying to write a basic dialog box. I want to be able to specify a link element which will launch a dialog box when clicked.

I'n specifying this behavior using data attributes in the dialog boxes HTML:

```
<a id="launch-dialog" href="#"></a>
<div class="dialog" data-behavior="dialog" data-trigger="#launch-dialog">
  <!-- dialog html -->
</div>

$(function(){
  $("[data-behavior='dialog']").dialog();
});
```

The actual jQuery extension is the part I'm having trouble with though. Either the `'dopen'` event isn't being triggered on the body correctly or else the event binding isn't being set up correctly. The click event on the `data-trigger` is definitely firing and being listened to though. Any ideas why I never see the "open detected" log?

```
(function($) {
  var methods = {
    init: function(options) {

      if (this.data('trigger')) {
        // Add an event listener which causes the dialog to
        // open when the correct link is clicked.
        $(this.data('trigger')).on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          // Trigger a global dialog open event which the dialog can subscribe to.
          $('body').trigger('dopen');
        });
      }
    },
    // Various other methods not shown.
  };

  $.fn.dialog = function(method) {

    // Method handling code not shown...

    // Add handlers for custom events triggered on the body element.
    $('body').bind('dopen', function(e) {
      // This never happns:
      console.log("Open detected");
    });

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally didn't give enough information in my question to be able to solve the problem.

Where I have

```
# Method handling code not shown...
```

in the question code, the real code has the following:

```
// If it corresponds to a method defined in the method object.
if (methods[method]) {
  return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
// Else, if we pass in an object and 
} else if ( _.isObject(method) || !method ) {
  return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
} else {
  $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.doalog' );
}
```

As you can see, that snippet has three possible paths:

1. Return the result of a method call,
2. Return the result of a method call,
3. Raise an exception.

Control flow was getting short-cut in these paths and wasn't reaching the line where I try to bind a listener. Of course, an unbound listener can never be fired.

The solution was to move the binding up into the initialization method:

```
  var methods = {
    init: function(options) {

      // Add handlers for custom events triggered on the body element.
      $('body').bind('dopen', function(e) {
        // Now it works!
        console.log("Open detected");
       });

      if (this.data('trigger')) {
        // Add an event listener which causes the dialog to
        // open when the correct link is clicked.
        $(this.data('trigger')).on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          // Trigger a global dialog open event which the dialog can subscribe to.
          $('body').trigger('dopen');
        });
      }
    },
    // Various other methods not shown.
  }
```